# Bounce card css animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm building a very simple bounce card animation, however at some point the animation got reseted and the result is not fluent.

Please check:

```css
    div{
      width: 110px;
      height: 50px;
      background: #EEE;
      border: 1px solid #BBB;
      border-radius: 3px;
      padding: 3px 5px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      left: 200px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    @keyframes cardBouncing {
    
      20%, 60%, to {
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 80deg);
        transform-origin: top left;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      }
    
      0%, 40%, 80% {
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
        transform-origin: top left;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      }
    }
    
    div{
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px grey;
      animation: 1.5s cardBouncing infinite; //flipInX;
    }
```

```html
<div>HOla!</div>
```

1. How I can make it bouncing without that "jump"
2. This is for a drag animation, how can I center in the mouse cursor position? It seems like it go to much at the left. It's possible?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is with: `animation-direction: alternate-reverse;`

```css
div{
  width: 110px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #EEE;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
}

@keyframes cardBouncing {
  from {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }

 to {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 80deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
}

div{
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px grey;
  animation: 0.4s cardBouncing infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div> Hola! </div>
```